# Bash - making decisions based upon output?

Tags: bash, git

I am scripting a lot of processes in BASH. I want to not build certain items if they are already up to date in Git.

if a `git pull` is issued and the results are something like:

```
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
From https://github.com/xxx/yyyy
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

How can I base decisions on the output of `git pull`?

Attempts:

```
upstream ⚡ master) 17≡ $ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

(upstream ⚡ master) 17≡ $ git pull origin master
From github.com:xxx/yyy  m
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

(upstream ⚡ master) 17≡ $ git pull origin master 2>/dev/null |grep -q "Already up-to-date"

(upstream ⚡ master) 17≡ $
```

Attempt 2:

```
$ git pull origin master 2>/dev/null | grep -q "Already up-to-date"; echo $?
1
$
```

Attempt 3:

```
$ git pull origin master 2>/dev/null |grep -q "Already up-to-date"; echo $?
1

$ git pull origin master
From github.com:cocos2d/cocos2d-x-docs
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git pull origin master 2>/dev/null |grep -q "Already up-to-date"; echo $?
1
```

Attempt 4:

```
$ git pull origin master 2>/dev/null |cat
Already up to date.

$ git pull origin master 2>/dev/null | grep -q "Already up-to-date"; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Can you give examples for the kinds of decisions you want to make?

Comment: @alfunx updated

Comment: @wjandrea various combinations of  `git pull | grep`, `git pull | xargs`; so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will [return true (0)](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) if the output of `git pull` contains `Already up-to-date`:

```
git pull | grep -q "Already up-to-date"
```

Then you can put it into an `if`-statement to take action conditionally. For example:

```
if git pull | grep -q "Already up-to-date"; then
    echo "Building stuff"
else
    echo "Not building stuff"
fi
```

---

Your attempts are failing because `git` is printing `up to date` without the dashes, but the `grep` command is searching for `up-to-date` with the dashes, which is what your example output says. (BTW I'm using git 2.7.4 which prints `up-to-date`.) This sort of output might change between versions of `git`, so there is a more stable way of checking this sort of output, but I'm not sure what it is :/

Comment: I thought so, but I tried: `$  git pull origin master | grep -q "Already up-to-date"` -- Output:

From github.com:xxx/yyy
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

Comment: @Jason Yes, those two lines are being printed to stderr, and the pipe only redirects stdout. It still returns true, right?

Comment: @Jason If you don't need the output on stderr, you can do `git pull 2>/dev/null | grep ...`.

Comment: @Jason Look at the exit code, e.g. run `echo $?` after running the command. `0` means true, anything else means false.

Comment: @alfunx ok, I ran: `$ git pull origin master 2>/dev/null | grep -q "Already up-to-date"; echo $?` and the code is "1". I updated the original post.

Comment: @Jason Then you know that the output from `git pull origin master 2>/dev/null` didn't contain `Already up-to-date`. It's working as it's supposed to.

Comment: @wjandrea - but that are indeed not any changes. Updated to attempt 3 above. It should be returning 0 from what I can tell.

Comment: @Jason Ah, I see the problem. Answer updated again.